# What is sct list in SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, config, tls1.2

What is sct list in SSL certificate? I had seen it in Google's SSL certificate.
And how to add it in a certificate using openssl?

```
e712f2b0377e1a62fb8ec90c6184f1ea7b37cb561d11265bf3e0f34bf241546e
‎Wednesday, ‎15 ‎July, ‎2020 5:29:23 PM
SHA256
ECDSA
304602210096c52ed8da6b4d3babfca5fdd1f75837fdd1a7e52eb9921ae5427cc33a9151ba022100e02b680bf63fd773b280c1f10c35de25bc6ba09423f8057819b40e9708a9dbd2

v1
07b75c1be57d68fff1b0c61d2315c7bae6577c5794b76aeebc613a1a69d3a21c
‎Wednesday, ‎15 ‎July, ‎2020 5:29:23 PM
SHA256
ECDSA
30440220412487d8eeda1cd592dcf550fd1d6b924007d91dfa1f10c521d224b2855e08fa0220528761cab1a239ae56d9ff841259f81a8039cfd78e0bb461ab8a496519431743
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a list of Signed Certificate Timestamps. These are part of [certificate transparency](https://www.certificate-transparency.org/how-ct-works), as defined in [RFC 6962](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc6962/).

The data contained in a SCT is as follows (using one of yours for an example):

- **Log ID**: `e712f2b0377e1a62fb8ec90c6184f1ea7b37cb561d11265bf3e0f34bf241546e` (this happens to be the [Let's Encrypt Oak2020 log](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/ct-logs/))
- **Issue Date**: ‎`Wednesday, ‎15 ‎July, ‎2020 5:29:23 PM`
- **Hash algorithm**: `SHA256`
- **Signature algorithm**: `ECDSA`
- **Signature data**: `304602210096c52ed8da6b4d3babfca5fdd1f75837fdd1a7e52eb9921ae5427cc33a9151ba022100e02b680bf63fd773b280c1f10c35de25bc6ba09423f8057819b40e9708a9dbd2`

When a CA issues a certificate, it records the certificate issuance with one or more CT log (publicly run servers that provably record certificate issuance).

The SCT indicates when the issuance occurred, which log it was recorded in, and how to find it (using the signature data). To verify that the information is correct, the client is supposed to verify that the certificate in the log matches the one you are verifying.

This is not something you should include in certificates you issue unless you happen to be running a public certificate authority. Self-signed certificates are not submitted to CT logs.

Comment: But I need the solution for adding CT log to a certificate in OpenSSL.

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: Did you submit the certificate to an active log? If so, that means you're a public CA. If not, there's nothing to add to the certificate.

Comment: No. How to summit a certificate to an active log and add sct list in the certificate?

Comment: Again, are you a public CA? If so, start by reading everything at [certificate-transparency.org](https://www.certificate-transparency.org/). If not, you can't submit private certificates to CT logs.

Comment: I am not sure I am a private CA or public CA. I am going to issue certificates for my domain only and only my computer trust my root CA.

Comment: Then this is a private certificate, you will not be able to submit it to a certificate log or obtain a corresponding SCT.

Comment: Well, it sounds like you really cannot issue self-signed certificates for testing purposes. I needed one for HashiCorp Vault, but on a Mac it appears Apple is checking for these SCTs and if your cert doesn't have it, Apple rejects it.

Answer (score 0):

In openssl use add extension by OID. in config file add 
`1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2 = ASN1:UTF8String:Hello! its my SCT data` 
and we have certificate with SCT! but reading further about SCT (Certificate Transparensy) you will understand, why openssl not supports SCT. 
And at the end I will say: you don't need to use SCT. Just forget about SCT. Don't use SCT, not necessary.